MongoDB Angular How to Can I insert a Duplicate Item If Create New Object ID
I need users to have the ability to add the same item into there cart even if it exist. If
I attempt to do this I will get a duplicate error.
I know one way is to just increase the count but this won't work for my case because there is a size involved as well.  When user clicks add to cart they must choose a size.  I came up way an idea to create a new objectId.  This is were I get stuck, I can't figure out how to insert the data coming from the client side or if this idea would even work   If any body can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.
Code snippet below:
 router.post('/getProducts/addtocart:_id',   async(req, res)=> {

  const _id = req.params._id;
    let productCart= await Products.findById({_id});

     mongoose.connect(mongoURI, function(err, db){
       assert.ok("1" == 1 );
         Cart.countDocuments({_id: productCart._id}, function (err, count){ 
           if(err){
             console.log(err)
              }else{
            console.log("Count:", count)
             }

         if(count>0){
           console.log("Product exist")
           newId=({"_id" : ObjectId()})
   
           console.log("what is new productCart ID", newId )
    
           db.collection('carts').insertOne(newId )// This works
      
         }else{

          do somethis else

         }     
   
      });

     });
       
   });          



Please opt one-to-many cardinality of relationship between the two collections Products and Carts.

Please keep the _id key in Carts as its primary key which is by default.

Please do not create a unique index on the foreign key productId in Carts.

If there is a data retrieval is required from Carts based on ProductId, then create an an ordinary (duplicate index) to aid the retrieval.


A sample schema of Carts may look like:
{
_id : ObjectId, unique: true, // by default
productId : ObjectId, ref: 'Products', Index: true,
...
}

Notes: Based on the business needs, a unique index on sessionId or userId + ProductId + Size may be considered.
